# Automatic restart of grails on execption

Tags: grails

I have an app, that is fairly large, and needs to be up all the time.

Over the weekend, I came back to it saying that it had a "Rollover failed exception". And this was displaying on every page of the app that I went to.

I believe the cause was because our network guys resat our firewall over the weekend and this caused Grails to lose connection with the databases, which then caused the exception.

I had to manually restart grails to get the app up and running again.

My question is, in the future, is there a way to automatically restart grails on exceptions like this?

Sorry, I come from a world of crash only design, where it's all scripts, so if something like that went wrong, it's just a matter of reloading the page.

Thanks

Comment: you should make this part of your monitoring and act there.  the app or the whole application server might end up in a state, where it is no longer able to detect a massive failure and react to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have some grails web-apps running on the jboss. But this is maybe any web-app even on PHP.
I'm monitoring their activity and restarting them via the next bash script in cron.
You may rewrite this to your needs.

```
#!/bin/bash
wget --timeout=3 --tries=1 --spider --no-check-certificate http://yoursite.url:8080

if [ $? -ne 0 ];then
  echo "Site Down. Restarting..."
  service jboss restart
  #mail -s "Site Down. Was restarted" your@e-mail.test
fi
```